# laravel notification queue response: "Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table"

Tags: laravel, notifications, queue, response, laravel-9

When I send a notification with Laravel 9, sometimes I get the response:

> `Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "550", with message "550 5.1.1 <test@myhostingservice.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table".`

The entire queue then breaks off and other e-mails that would work are not sent either. With GMX or GMAIL it works, but with a few emails from hosting-services this message appears.

I've already tried a `try and catch` method, but without success:

```
use Exception;

try {
    Notification::route('mail', $email_adresses)->notify(new MinStock($item));
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    logger('Notification Exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n");
}
```

I could change something on the server side, but that's not the solution, since I don't have access to all servers.

It would be nice if the `try and catch` method would work and I could inform the user about the non-existent email address.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The error message **Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table** indicates that the email address you are trying to send the notification to does not exist or is not recognized by the email service provider [1](https://clients.websavers.ca/whmcs/knowledgebase/181/You-receive-a-bounce-message-that-says-User-unknown-in-virtual-alias-table.html).

You can add validation(with laravel Validator) before the `notify()` to the email and use some rules for [emails](https://laravel.com/docs/9.X/validation#rule-email).